# OpenCL 1D Array Big Number Multiply

Tags: c, opencl, gpgpu

I am working on multiplying two integer array for big numbers. I basically multiplied about 20 digits numbers but for more numbers it acts unstable. I have some code on CPU and kernel for test and kernel give me different numbers after each work. The problem may be barrier or something like mutex but im not into this that much. How can i solve this unstability? Here is the code

```
kernel void multiply(global int* A,
                 const int M,
                 global int* B,
                 const int N,
                 global int* C){
const int globalRow = get_global_id(0); // Row ID of C (0..M)
int globalCol,i;

// Compute a single element (loop over K)
for (globalCol=0; globalCol<N; globalCol++) {
    int val=A[globalRow]*B[globalCol];

    printf("Row is %d , Col is %d \n",globalRow,globalCol);
    //C[globalCol + globalRow +1]+=val/10;
    C[globalCol + globalRow]+=val%10;

    C[globalCol+1+globalRow]+=val/10;

}

int flag=1;
while (flag) {
    flag=0;
    for (i=M+N-1   ; i>=0 ; i--) {
        if (C[i]>9) {
            C[i+1]+=C[i]/10;
            C[i]=C[i]%10;
            flag=1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

the flag thing on code is shifting.It sounds like accessing elements problem but i don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a race condition. Adjacent threads are accessing the same memory location, at the same time, at the two lines of code doing += with the C array. Since these follow a specific pattern you could use `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)` between the two += operations to remove the race condition. I think you have something similar in the carry code below. Be careful there as *all threads in a work group must hit the barrier*, or your kernel will hang or crash.

Comment: Thank you so much. I realized a race condition at there but that barrier thing i barely understand. Is this work like ;
mutex_lock and mutex_unlock like; for running between mutexes
barrier and barrier executes the same way. This is my theory but the compiler doesn't think like me i guess

Comment: A barrier is like a meeting point; all work items in a work group gather there before moving on to the next part of code. The first one there parks, as do others, until the last one there makes all the parked ones continue. In this case, it ensures all the += of the first C locations finish before doing the offset ones, which removes the race condition. You might find this tool useful (it is not mine): http://multicore.doc.ic.ac.uk/tools/GPUVerify/

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stucked there.